# Traversing un-ordered list and appending attibute values to the list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this jQuery code to traverse the HTML markup. Basically, I am selecting `data-icount` attribute of each anchor tag and appending it to anchor text as `(28)` e.g. the ALL becomes `ALL (38)` in the example. `38` here is the sum of all the `data-icount`s under that `li`. Similarly, `summers` become `summers (2)` because it has two data-icount 0 and 2 so 0+2 =2.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GQkB8/).

I am sure there must be an improved process to do this - any comments/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $lis = $("#tree li");   
        $lis.each(function(index) {         
            var $this = $(this);
            var $sub_uls = $this.children('ul');
            var $child_a = $this.children('a');
            var num_sub_uls = $sub_uls.length;

            var count_icount = 0;
            if(num_sub_uls > 0) {
                //var sub_lis = $this.children('a');
                var sub_lis = $sub_uls.find('a');
                //console.log('Total anchors: '+sub_lis.length);
                sub_lis.each(function(index2) {
                    count_icount += parseInt($(this).attr('data-icount'));
                    //console.log(count_icount);
                });
                //console.log("out of loop");
            } else {
                count_icount = parseInt($child_a.attr('data-icount'));
            }

            var a_txt = $child_a.text();
            $child_a.text(a_txt+' ('+count_icount+') ');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="tree" class="tree">
    <li class="">
        <a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/1">ALL </a>
        <ul >
            <li class="">
                <a data-icount="7" href="/some/thing/2" >Fruits</a>
                <ul >
                    <li class="">
                        <a data-icount="5" href="/some/thing/4" >Summers</a>
                        <ul >
                            <li class=""><a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/7">Mango</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-icount="2" href="/some/thing/8" >Water melon</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/5" >Winters</a>
                        <ul >
                            <li class=""><a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/9" >Tangerines</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/10" >Pomegranate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a data-icount="1" href="/some/thing/12" >Others</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
                <a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/3" class="selected">Furniture</a>
                <ul >
                    <li class=""><a data-icount="6" href="/some/thing/6" >Home</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/11" >Garden</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a data-icount="10" href="/some/thing/13" >Games</a>
                <ul >
                    <li class=""><a data-icount="5" href="/some/thing/36" >Playstation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a data-icount="2" href="/some/thing/37" >Clothes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tips:

### 1) Don't create variables if they're only used once or are a don't perform complex operations.

Old Code:

```
var num_sub_uls = $sub_uls.length;
var count_icount = 0;
if(num_sub_uls > 0) {
```

New Code:

```
var count_icount = 0;
if($sub_uls.length) {
```

### 2) Provide the base when using `parseInt()`.

Old Code:

```
count_icount = parseInt($child_a.attr('data-icount'));
```

New Code:

```
count_icount = parseInt($child_a.attr('data-icount'), 10);
```

### 3) Eliminate commented code sections.

Old code:

```
var sub_lis = $sub_uls.find('a');
//console.log('Total anchors: '+sub_lis.length);
sub_lis.each(function(index2) {
```

New Code:

```
var sub_lis = $sub_uls.find('a');
sub_lis.each(function(index2) {
```

### 4) Simplify if conditions by using Truthy & Falsey .

```
Boolean(undefined); // => false
Boolean(null); // => false
Boolean(false); // => false
Boolean(0); // => false
Boolean(""); // => false
Boolean(NaN); // => false

Boolean(1); // => true
Boolean([1,2,3]); // => true
Boolean(function(){}); // => true
```

[More here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/)

Old Code:

```
if(num_sub_uls > 0) {
```

New Code:

```
if(num_sub_uls) {
```

### 5) Use `.append()` to append text to an element in jQuery.

Old Code:

```
var a_txt = $child_a.text();
$child_a.text(a_txt+' ('+count_icount+') ');
```

New Code:

```
$child_a.children('a').append( ' (' + count_icount + ') ' );
```

### 6) Simplify your `if` and `else` conditions.

Check if `count_icount` is greater than 0, instead of checking for `sub_list.length`;

Old Code:

```
if(num_sub_uls > 0) {
    var sub_lis = $sub_uls.find('a');
    sub_lis.each(function(index2) {
        count_icount += parseInt($(this).attr('data-icount'));
    });
} else {
    count_icount = parseInt($child_a.attr('data-icount'));
}
```

New Code:

```
$sub_uls.find('a').each(function(index2) {
    count_icount += parseInt($(this).attr('data-icount'));
});
if( !count_icount ){
    count_icount = parseInt($this.children('a').attr('data-icount'), 10);
}
```

### 7) Use `.data()` instead of `.attr()` to access properties that begin with `data-`.

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) Documentation

Example:

```
<a id="thing2" data-icount="9" href="/some/thing/2" >Fruits</a>
```

Use

```
$("#thing2").data( "icount" ) == "9";
```

Instead of

```
$("#thing2").attr( "data-icount" ) == "9";
```

### Final code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree li").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
        count_icount = $this.find("a").data('icount');

        $this.children('ul').find('a').each(function () {
            count_icount += parseInt($(this).data('icount'), 10);
        });
        if (!count_icount) {
            count_icount = parseInt($this.children('a').data('icount'), 10);
        }
        $this.children('a').append(' (' + count_icount + ') ');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GQkB8/2/

Comment: While I +1 this It would be good to explain a few things here. Specifically A lot of new javascripters will not understand the whole `parseInt("09")` issue. It would be good to include that detail here so others can understand your reasoning.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I'll keep parseInt tip in my mind. Some of the other things like comments, and `num_lis_length > 0` I kept to make code more obvious to understand but I get your point.

Comment: Hi Larry - the count of very first LI's Anchor (`<a data-icount="0" href="/some/thing/1">ALL </a>` doesn't get added? for example, if I change it to `5` i.e. `<a data-icount="5" href="/some/thing/1">ALL </a>` it still reads as `(38)` ... any ideas how to fix this? thx

Comment: In fact that is true with all other Anchors ... that is it shows count of children only ... can it be changed to include the parent count itself too? e.g. in the demo markup, `Summers (2) ` becomes `Summers (7)` because `Summers` itself has `5` as icount.

Comment: @HappyApe You found a bug with your original code then. :)

Comment: @HappyApe The value of the current list wasn't being set. Change `count_icount` to `count_icount = $this.find("a").data('icount');` I updated my code to fix the problem.

Comment: Excellent! thanks very much Larry! yes I found bug in my code.. lol ... actually I had written that code and then got busy so I couldn't really test it after you gave your answer but seems all ok now. Cheers

Comment: Also noticed that you replaced `attr()` with `data()` - nice :)